# IBoutlet getting nil while loading attributed text

Tags: uitableview, iboutlet, custom-cell

Im struggling to fix one issue with IBOutlet in Custom Table View Cell. Actually I have a tableview with custom cell, designed in storyboard itself, there I have 4 labels to show different kind of information to user. All 3 labels are getting values, but one label is showing nil. I checked everything like connections from storyboard and awakeFromNib(). But still it is getting nil. I will appreciate someone help in this..

Answer (score 0):

It can bee solved by checking the connection of that perticular IBOutlet. The only reason is the IBOutlet connection between the class and the storyboard is not proper.